# What is the relation between the count of tasks and the actionable task displayed in the output of gradle build command?

Tags: gradle

When I run `gradlew build`, I get this output. Nothing extraordinary but I see there are total 13 task (I have numbered them for ease of understanding below).

However later, I get the output `4 actionable tasks: 4 up-to-date`

```
10:36:22 PM: Executing task 'build'...

1       > Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
2       > Task :compileScala UP-TO-DATE
3       > Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
4       > Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
5       > Task :jar UP-TO-DATE
6       > Task :assemble UP-TO-DATE
7       > Task :compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
8       > Task :compileTestScala UP-TO-DATE
9       > Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
10      > Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
11      > Task :test UP-TO-DATE
12      > Task :check UP-TO-DATE
13      > Task :build UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 211ms
4 actionable tasks: 4 up-to-date
10:36:22 PM: Task execution finished 'build'.
```

My question is whether there is a relation between the `4 actionable tasks: 4 up-to-date` and the 13 `Tasks` (dependencies?!?!) ?

If yes, then how are there only 4 actionable tasks mentioned? And if not how can I see those 4 actionable tasks? What are they exactly?

Sorry, if this sound basic, I have searched around this topic a lot and I was not able to find any relevant answer/topic.